# Desenvolvimento Android com Android Studio - RecyclerView não está funcionando

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estou tentando entrar nesse mundo de desenvolvimento Android, usando Android Studio. E logo no começo já enfrento um problema simples para um programador experiente que usa Android Studio mas relativamente difícil para quem está começando.

O problema é o seguinte: O meu preview do layout não mostra a RecyclerView, consequentemente meu app, na hora de testá-lo, sequer chega abrir onde estou tentando usá-lo. Já tentei as recomendações do curso que estou seguindo, mas nada funciona.

**Aqui está o build.gradle(Module:app), onde coloquei as dependências:**

[image: Imagem do build.gradle(Module:app)]

**Como fica o preview, no canto direito da tela:**

[image: imagem2]

Comment: Primeiro, evita usar mesmas bibliotecas com versões diferentes. Segundo, abra aquelas exclamação em azul no canto superior direito da tela que dirá o que está faltando.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, Ascension.

Comment: Veja isto também Mateus: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/devemos-cortar-a-mania-das-perguntas-com-imagem-do-c%C3%B3digo-ao-inv%C3%A9s-do-c%C3%B3digo

Comment: Já resolveu? Se não, envia sua Class pro pessoal lhe ajudar... Reparei que no seu RecyclerView não possui o código abaixo, veja se é necessário; ... tools:listitem="@layout/seu_item">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Mateus!

Confirme se seu Android Studio está atualizado. Em **Help** > **Check for Updates...**

Modifique a implementação dos componentes para:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

E... certifique-se que o `support:appcompat` não fique duplicado.

Comment: O Android Studio sempre que atualiza surge um probleminha, mas consegui resolver atualizando-o. Obrigado.